# How can I map an Object field on mongodb to a struct on Golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I have the following document on mongodb:

```
{
    "random": {
          "is_it_true": true
    }
}
```

And i want to read it and map it on the following struct on Golang:

```
type StructGolang struct {
    IsItTrue bool `bson:"random.is_it_true"`
}
```

But it isn't working. I'm getting an error when executing the Find command on the database.

Comment: Can you share the golang code, where you are performing the find operation? Also, share the error which you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your document is:

```
{
    "name": "some str-1",
    "random": {
          "isTrue": true
    }
}
```

You can model your document as one of the following (depends upon your usage):

```
type Random struct {
    IsTrue bool
}

type MyObj struct {
    Name string
    Random Random
}
```

Or,

```
type MyObj struct {
    Name string
    Random map[string]bool
}
```

Then query as follows:

```
var result MyObj
err := collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), bson.D{{}}).Decode(&result)
```